# parse-dashboard running on local parse-server errors out in with: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Tags: parse-server, parse-dashboard

While setting up a local test environment with parse-server and parse-dashboard an error is displayed in the browser and the screen is just blank white.

mongodb-runner is running and working on mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/parse

parse-server is running and working on http://localhost:1337/parse

parse-dashboard is loaded with the following information and running:

parse-dashboard --dev --appId yourAppId --masterKey yourMasterKey --serverURL "http://localhost:1337/parse" --appName optionalName

I received the appId together with the master key and mongodb instance during the setup of parse-server based on the prerequisites of installation http://docs.parseplatform.org/parse-server/guide/ with this command: sh <(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/parse-community/parse-server/master/bootstrap.sh) which allowed me to generate the id and key

In addition I am using MongoDB Compass to review the database and everything looks great. I have been able to create a document by using simple curl -X POST 
-H "X-Parse-Application-Id: APPLICATION_ID" 
-H "Content-Type: application/json" 
-d '{"score":123,"playerName":"Sean Plott","cheatMode":false}' 
http://localhost:1337/parse/classes/GameScore

I am able to access the parse dashboard on http://0.0.0.0:4040
The browser screen shows the parse-dashboard colourful circles for a second and then turns blank white with the above error message in console.

I should also add that if I change the parameters in parse-dashboard command to use a cloud parse-server everything works fine, which makes me believe there is something not right with the parse-server running locally.

[Screenshot of Javascript Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vXPgf.png)

[Screenshot of Network Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3Loh.png)

Answer (score 0):

It looks your Parse Server is listening http but the dashboard is trying to use https. Please try `--serverURL "http://localhost:1337/parse"` instead of `--serverURL "https://localhost:1337/parse"`

Comment: Thank you Davi, this was unfortunately a typo on my end. I updated the question to reflect the correct settings which I have tried without success.

Comment: Would you mind to try opening the dashboard on `http://localhost:4040`?

Comment: I tried opening the dashboard on http://localhost:4040 as suggested but the problem remains unfortunately.

Comment: Could you share everything you see on your browser console and also on the requests that are failing on your network tab?

Comment: Hello and thanks for replying. I have edited the original post to include the two screen shots.

Comment: What is the Parse Dashboard version that you are running?

Comment: I am using parse-dashboard: "^3.2.1"

Comment: The only thing that I noticed is that parse dashboard should be connecting to `http://localhost:1337/parse/schemas` (for example). But it is actually connecting to `http://localhost:1337/parse%E2%80%9D/schemas`. So it looks that the server url that you are sending on the parse-dashboard command is still wrong. Would you mind to share again the command you are using to run parse-dashboard (with http and without ")?

Comment: BTW, when I decode your current server url, that's what I have: `decodeURI('http://localhost:1337/parse%E2%80%9D/schemas')` => `'http://localhost:1337/parse”/schemas'`. So it looks that you still have the `”` char on your server url.

Comment: Thank you Davi for helping out here, unfortunately I had to put this on hold for a while, using Mongoose for now. I hope to be able to test this out shortly and reply.